# Excel, Auto Fill Date Range, One Cell each Date Range

Tags: excel

How do I get a date range in one cell then autofill the rest of the dates? For exampe in cell B2 I would like, Jan 1 - Jan 7 and in cell C2,  Jan 8 - Jan 14.

Comment: This will be recognized as a string by excel which is not the best at auto filling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use helper columns and `TEXT()`

Create two columns with the dates in question like:

```
   A            B
2019-01-01  2019-01-07
2019-01-08  2019-01-14
```

Two rows is enough for Excel to understand the pattern.

In C1 you add the following formula:

```
=TEXT(A1,"MMM D")&" - "&TEXT(B1,"MMM D")
```

Now you can use fill down to fill down the dates for however long you need.
If you don't want/need the helper columns then copy column C and paste as values, now you can remove column A and B.

[image]

Comment: I used this solution because it was much easier to change the date ranges! Thanks much!

Comment: Your solution/follow up effort have more detail (printscreen) + practical (better user friendliness, by separating the input part).  Congratulations. (:     || @BeginnerKruman you may click on the small "tick" beside this answer post to "accept" this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in C2 :

```
=TEXT(DATE(2019,1,1+(COLUMN(C1)-3)*7),"mmm d")&" - "&TEXT(DATE(2019,1,1+(COLUMN(C1)-3)*7+6),"mmm d")
```

Then drag rightwards.

Idea : Use cell column value to dictate which date to print/display.

Hope it helps. ( :